# How can I spy on this method that returns a promise?

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using Mocha with Sinon to test my Angular app. I'm having trouble using a spy for a method that returns a promise. Here is my test:

```
describe('product model', function() {
    'use strict';

    var mockProductsResource, Product;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app.models')

        mockProductsResource = {
            all: sinon.spy(),
            find: sinon.spy(),
            create: sinon.spy()
        };
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('productsResource', mockProductsResource);
        })

        inject(function($injector) {
            Product = $injector.get('Product');
        })
    });

    describe('module', function() {
        // THE TEST THAT IS FAILING
        it('should find one record', function() {
            Product.find(1);
            expect(mockProductsResource.find).to.should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });
});
```

When this runs I get

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'productsResource.all().then')

because my spy for productsResource.all() does not return a promise, which the code I am testing that uses productsResource.all() expects:

```
angular.module('app.models').factory('Product', ['productsResource', function(productsResource) {

    // Constructor function for models
    function Product(attributes) {
        // ...
    }

    // Public "instance" methods for models

    Product.prototype.update = function() {
        // ...
    };

    Product.prototype.save = function() {
        // ...
    };

    Product.prototype.remove = function() {
        // ...
    };


    // Public "class" methods for this factory

    // THE METHOD I AM TESTING
    function all() {
        return productsResource.all().then(function(response) {
            var products = [], index;

            for (index in response.data) {
                products.push(new Product(response.data[index]));
            }

            return products;
        });
    }

    function find(id) {
        return productsResource.find(id).then(function(response) {
            return new Product(response.data);
        });
    }

    function create(attributes) {
        return productsResource.create(attributes);
    }

    return {
        all: all,
        find: find,
        create: create
    };

}]);
```

Any ideas how to use a spy and make this test work?

Answer (score 0):

Inject $q and

```
var deferred = $q.defer;
mockProductsResource = {
        all: function() {
            return deferred.promise
        },
        ... and so on
};

sinon.spy(mockProductsResource, "all");
```

from the sinon documentation:

> var spy = sinon.spy(object, "method");
>
> Creates a spy for object.method and replaces the original method with
>   the spy. The spy acts exactly like the original method in all cases.
>   The original method can be restored by calling
>   object.method.restore(). The returned spy is the function object which
>   replaced the original method. spy === object.method.

Comment: Or this might be a complicated way for this. Better way is probably to use [a mock backend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) in case of $http use or just not bothering with $q and using spy on existing methods (if existing service returns stuff without breaking).